# Excel Userform to only show if linked worksheet is active

Tags: vba

hoping someone can help. I'm very new to VB code.

I'm building a set of Userforms where the data input is linked to various different worksheets. What i want is for my Userform Continue command buttons to only proceed to a certain Userform if the corresponding worksheet is active.

Eg My "Buildings" Userform must only display if Sheet "Buildings" is active on the workbook.
If Sheet "Buildings" is not active then the code must look for the next active sheet and go to the Userform that is linked to that sheet.

Eg If Sheet "Contents" is active on the workbook then the code must show my "Contents" Userform I created.

My first Userform asks the user to select which worksheets must be active by clicking on Toggle Buttons that activate sheets in the workbook.

From there the user clicks on a "Continue" button and then I need my code to look at which sheets are active.

I have this so far but I know its incorrect...

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim answer As Integer
answer = MsgBox("Have you selected all your sections?", vbYesNo + 
vbQuestion, "Selection Query")
If answer = vbYes And Sheets("Buildings") = Active Then
Me.Hide
Buildings_UF.Show
Else

Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

Thanking in advance
Patrick

Comment: Usually in Excel when we speak of "Active" worksheet it has a very specific meaning, it is the currently displayed worksheet. You seems to use "Active" in an other way, could you please tell us more? Is there anywhere you are storing if a sheet is active or not?

Comment: Hi Vincent,

Thanks for your reply.  Sorry by active i mean unhidden. The sheets are hidden until the user selects to unhide them with the Toggle Buttons as mentioned..

Comment: So i should rather say if the sheet is visible in the workbook then the corresponding userform should show.

Comment: Do you want the sheet active so you can place data on it from VBA?  I'm asking as the sheet doesn't actually need to be active or visible - `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Buildings").Range("A1") = 1` will always place that value in the correct place no matter which workbook or sheet is currently active. With that you could have one form with a _tab strip_ or _multipage_ control.

Comment: I would personally create a Public Sub in each form in charge of checking if the relevant sheet is visible or not and displaying the userform or calling the next one.

Comment: Hi Darren,I need the sheet(s) visible because at a later point the user might need to access a particular sheet to further edit certain data on it. If the sheet is hidden they wont be able to.

Comment: Darren your suggestion for a tab strip or multipage sounds good. My only problem might be spacing on the one form. Each Insurance section (Buildings, Contents, Motor, etc will have multiple items with the same repeating insurance queries. So i'm not sure if I'd get all that onto 1 form? I'll play around and see thanks

Comment: @ Vincent, thanks I'll have a look into Public Subs. Not sure of the coding to check if the relevant sheet is visible or not :)

Answer (score 0):

`UserForm.Show` will stop the sub execution while the userform is opened, so the following code should suffice (untested code):

```
If answer = vbYes Then
    Me.Hide
    If Worksheets("Buildings").Visible then Buildings_UF.Show
    If Worksheets("OtherSheet").Visible then OtherSheet_UF.Show    
    ...
End If
```

Comment: Mmm, i tried that code but its giving me a subscript out of range message If Worksheets("Building Items 1,2,3").Visible Then

Comment: Do you have a Worksheet named "Building Items 1,2,3"?

Comment: Yes I do.  I just simplified it to "Buildings" in my post

Comment: Make sure there is no typo nor leading or trailing spaces, because if you get the "subscript out of range" error here it means there is no worksheet with such name.

Comment: Thanks. i must have had something wrong in the name.. Retyped it and now it works! Thanks Vincent, appreciate the help

Comment: If the solution works for you, do not hesitate to flag it as accepted answer.